# show the values on button click from span class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, class

i want to show the values from span class on button click. I already post one question. but it is working in fiddle only not my page.. so again i post this question with modification..

I have the following fields..

```
<th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
  <span class="font18">Rs.360</span> 
  <br />
</th>

  <th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
     <a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn"onclick="returnsms_confirm.call(this)"/></a>
  </th>


 <th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
   <span class="font18">Rs.1000</span> <span class="font20"></span></th>

    <th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
            <a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn" /></a></th>
```

this is my original code..

when the button is clicking it takes the amount of related span class..

*Jquery code*

```
function sms_confirm() {

       var r = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $("span[class^='font']").text() + " amount")

       if (r == false) {
           return false;
       }

   }
```

The above jquery code gives me the result of

```
Confirm the order to buy Rs.360 Rs.1000 amount
```

like that... I want to show single amount for single button click.. how will do this in jquery?

Comment: how is `sms_confirm` called?

Comment: on button click only.. i add onclick="return sms_confirm()" in button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="return sms_confirm.call(this)"/>
```

then

```
function sms_confirm() {
    var r = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $(this).prev("span[class^='font']").text() + " amount")

    return r;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mmTNZ/)

I would recommend using jQuery to register the event handlers like

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-buy" onclick="return sms_confirm.call(this)" />
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.btn-buy').click(function () {
        return confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $(this).prev("span[class^='font']").text() + " amount")
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZBXSY/)

Comment: For me it is not working.. I don't know why.. But i am using this span and button as different <th> within table..

Comment: still it is showing the answer "confirm the order to buy amount" i will update my correct html..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var ans = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $(this).prev('.font18').text() + " amount");
    return ans;
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TMGW/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to access immediately preceding sibling .

```
var r = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $(this).prev("span[class='font18']").text() + " amount")
```